# How to show a "Please wait " modal form from a TThread and free it when the job is done?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-10-seattle

I've been working just for a while trying to make a modal form to inform the user to wait until the job is ends.
This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
  TLoader = class(TThread)
    private
      FStrings: TStrings;
      procedure ShowWait;
      procedure EndsWait;
    public
      Constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings);
      Destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  List: TStrings;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    // Load Some Data here
    TLoader.Create(List);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

{ TLoader }

constructor TLoader.Create(AStrings: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
  FStrings:= TStringList.Create;
  FStrings.AddStrings(AStrings);
end;

destructor TLoader.Destroy;
begin
  FStrings.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TLoader.EndsWait;
begin
  TForm(Application.FindComponent('FWait')).Free;
end;

procedure TLoader.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Synchronize(ShowWait);
  // Do Some Job while not terminated
  Sleep(1000);
  // Free Wait Form
  // This part is not working
  Synchronize(EndsWait);
end;

procedure TLoader.ShowWait;
begin
  With TForm.Create(Application) do
    begin
      // Some code
      Name:= 'FWait';
      ShowModal;
    end;
end;

end.
```

Everything is working as I expected, except `Synchronize(EndsWait);` which did not close and free the modal form.

How can I display a modal form while a `TThread` is running and free it when the `TThread` terminated?

---

UPDATE:

I've try to do as Remy suggest as the following:

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
  TLoader = class(TThread)
    protected
      procedure DoTerminate; override;
      procedure DoCloseModal;
    public
      constructor Create;
      procedure Execute; override;
  end;
var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TLoader }

constructor TLoader.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
end;

procedure TLoader.DoCloseModal;
begin
  Form2.ModalResult:= mrOk;
end;

procedure TLoader.DoTerminate;
begin
  inherited DoTerminate;
  Synchronize(DoCloseModal);
end;

procedure TLoader.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  Sleep(200);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TLoader.Create;
end;

end.
```

The main form button click event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
    try
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: The new code you posted doesn't work because `Form2.ModalResult:= mrOk;` refers to the variable `Form2` which has nothing to do with the form object you create in `TForm1.Button1Click`. Indeed, there you create a `TForm2` without assigning it to any variable. The global `Form2` variable either isn't used at all or points to a different instance. Typically these automatically created global variables are used for auto-created forms. You need to to give the thread the pointer to the actual `TForm2` instance. For example, you can do this by creating a new ctor for the `TThread` that takes this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Do not use a modal form to begin with. `TThread.Synchronize()` blocks your thread until the synced method exits, but `TForm.ShowModal()` blocks that method until the Form is closed.  Use `TThread.Synchronize()` (or better, `TThread.Queue()`) to `Create()`+`Show()` (not `ShowModal()`) the Wait Form, then return to the thread and let it do its work as needed, then `Synchronize()`/`Queue()` again (or, use the thread's `OnTerminate` event) to `Close()`+`Free()` the Wait Form when done.
2. alternatively, if you want to use a modal Wait Form, then do not let the thread manage the Wait Form at all.  Have your button `OnClick` handler `Create()`+`ShowModal()` (not `Show()`) the Wait Form, and `Free()` it when `ShowModal()` exits.  Have the Wait Form internally create and terminate the thread when the Wait Form is shown and closed, respectively.  If the thread ends before the Wait Form is closed, the thread's `OnTerminate` handler can `Close()` the Form (which simply sets the Form's `ModalResult`) so that `ShowModal()` will exit in the `OnClick` handler.

Comment: Yup Remy, I want to use a modal form `ShowModal` instead of `Show`. I'll give it a try then get back to you soon. Thanks

Comment: @Ilyes: You want [UI modality](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050218-00/?p=36413) but probably don't care that much about code modality. You can get UI modality without code modality easily (basically just disable the form).

Comment: Well, setting `WaitForm.ModalResult:= MrOk;` in the `DoTerminate` body didn't works as well. I'll post an edit

Comment: @Remy, I've accepted your answer because the first way you provide works fine. Please can you provide an example for the second one?

Comment: @Ilyes most likely, your thread is setting `ModalResult` before `ShowModal()` is ready. After `ShowModal()` fires `OnShow` and `OnActivate`, and just before entering its modal loop, it resets the `ModalResult` to 0. So, if the thread sets the `ModalResult` before that happens, the thread's assignment will be lost. Instead of using `TThread.Synchronize()`, try using `TThread.Queue()` instead. Or, try using `PostMessage()` to post a delayed `WM_CLOSE` to the modal Form. Otherwise, you could use a `TTimer` on the modal Form to check the thread's `Terminated`/`Finished` property periodically.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I made a `uWaitForm.pas` unit:

```
unit uWaitForm;

interface

uses
  System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms;

type
  TWaitForm = class(TForm)
    private
      FThread: TThread;
    protected
      procedure Activate; override;
      procedure DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction); override;
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;
  TWaitThread = class(TThread)
    private
      FForm: TWaitForm;
      FModalResult: TModalResult;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
      procedure DoSetModalResult;
    public
      constructor Create(AForm: TWaitForm);
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TWaitForm }

procedure TWaitForm.Activate;
begin
  inherited;
  FThread:= TWaitThread.Create(Self);
end;

constructor TWaitForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited CreateNew(AOwner);
  Name:= 'WaitForm';
  BorderStyle:= bsDialog;
  Caption:= 'Please wait...';
  Width:= 200;
  Height:= 150;
  Position:= poDesktopCenter;
end;

destructor TWaitForm.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FThread) then
    FThread.Terminate;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWaitForm.DoClose(var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(FThread) then
    begin
      TWaitThread(FThread).FModalResult:= mrCancel;
      FThread.Terminate;
    end;

end; 


{ TWaitThread }

constructor TWaitThread.Create(AForm: TWaitForm);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FreeOnTerminate:= True;
  FForm:= AForm;
  FModalResult:= mrOk;
end;

destructor TWaitThread.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FForm) then
    Synchronize(nil, DoSetModalResult);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWaitThread.DoSetModalResult;
begin
  FForm.ModalResult:= FModalResult;
end;

procedure TWaitThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  // Do the work while not terminated
  // You can check for Terminated here and set FModalResult accordingly to receive it from ShowModal
  // By default it's mrOk (Job is done, the thread doesn't cancled)
  Sleep(200);
end;

end.
```

Then use it

```
  with TWaitForm.Create(nil) do
    try
      //Get ModalResult here and do something accordingly
      // mrCancel means the dialog form closed and the the Thread job aborted
      // mrOk The job is done and the form closed
      ShowModal;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
```